# Vue.js custom event naming

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two components, one contains another.

And when I trigger event from child I can't receive it in parent.

Child component

```
this.$emit('myCustomEvent', this.data);
```

Parent component

```
<parent-component v-on:myCustomEvent="doSomething"></parent-component>
```

But, when I changed event name to **my-custom-event** in both places it works.

Vue somehow transform event names?  Or what can be a problem?
I read [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Component-Naming-Conventions) about component naming convention but there nothing related to event naming

Answer (score 45):

**It is recommended to always use `kebab-case` for the naming of custom events.** Lower case events, all smashed together, as recommended by @KoriJohnRoys would also work but are harder to read. It is not recommended to use `camelCase` for event naming.

The [official documentation of Vue.JS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) states the following under the topic of Event Names:

> #### Event Names
>
> Unlike components and props, event names don’t provide any automatic case transformation. Instead, the name of an emitted event must exactly match the name used to listen to that event. For example, if emitting a camelCased event name:
>
> ```
> this.$emit('myEvent')
> ```
>
> Listening to the kebab-cased version will have no effect:
>
> ```
> <my-component v-on:my-event="doSomething"></my-component>
> ```
>
> Unlike components and props, event names will never be used as variable or property names in JavaScript, so there’s no reason to use camelCase or PascalCase. Additionally, v-on event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s case-insensitivity), so v-on:myEvent would become v-on:myevent – making myEvent impossible to listen to.
>
> For these reasons, we recommend you **always use kebab-case for event names.**

Comment: @Gjaa I've just retested it in Vue 2.6.10 and it still behaves the same. You probably have a problem somewhere else. Could you give some more information or ask a new question here on StackOverflow?

Comment: I had to emit my event using kebab case too for it to work, `this.$emit('my-event')`. Using camel case on my `$emit` didn't work :shrug:

Comment: *It is recommended to always use **kebab-case** for the naming of custom events.* Using camelCase won't work.

Comment: Beware: this ONLY applies to `Vue 2`! 
Whereas Vue3 allows camelCase https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/custom-event-name-casing.html

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @ssc-hrep3's point on `kebab-case`

The docs for [.sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) recommend using the pattern `update:myPropName`

Answer (score 1):

*For custom events*, the safest option is to just use a lower-cased event name all smashed together. Currently even kebab-case can have issues.

```
this.$emit('mycustomevent', this.data);
```

then, in the parent component, feel free to bind to a camel-cased function

```
<parent-component v-on:mycustomevent="doSomething"></parent-component>
```

it's a bit janky, but it works.

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4044) (states that kebab-case doesn't work either)

Comment: v2 guide has an explanation as well: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: The linked issue states that *mixing* camel case with kebab-case doesn't work. Kebab-case by itself `this.$emit('my-event', this.data);` and `v-on:my-event="doSomething"` works just fine.

Answer (score -6):

Vue.js transforms not only xml tags (component names) but attributes as well, so when you are generating event

`$emit('iLikeThis')`

you must handle it as:

`v-on:i-like-this="doSomething"`

From docs:

> When registering components **(or props)**, you can use kebab-case,
> camelCase, or TitleCase.
> ...
>
> Within HTML templates though, you **have to** use the kebab-case
> equivalents:

Comment: Not working. Vue doesn't transform camelCase to kebab...
But if I emit event in kebab style and listen it also in kebab style it works.

Comment: same here.. this doesn't seem to work for events (anymore). Using v2.4.2

Comment: It's not a wiki, but an answer to the question, which is valid and correct. Use documentation for ...documentation of the newer feature @ssc-hrep3.

Comment: Here's a link to documentation that explicitly says that the above won't work: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: This is not true for custom event naming