# Child component not emitting inside functions of methods object

Tags: vue.js

My parent component has the next piece of code:

```
<v-dialog max-width="400" v-model="loginDialog" @login-success="loginDialog = false"><login-component></login-component></v-dialog>
```

And my child component has this one:

```
methods: {
    async handleLoginForm() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$http.post('/api/users/login', { user: this.user })
        this.$store.dispatch('authenticate', response.data.user)
        this.$emit('login-success')
      } catch(error) {
        this.$swal.mixin({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000
        }).fire({
          type: 'error',
          title: error.message
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Everything works find in my `handleLoginForm()` method except for one thing: `this.$emit('login-success')` which does nothing. Is there anything wrong with my code?

**Edit:** I just changed my code and the kamel-case recommendation does not work.

Comment: Vue recommends always using kebab-case for event names. Try changing `'loginSuccess'` / `@loginSuccess` to `'login-success'` / `@login-success`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js custom event naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441952/vue-js-custom-event-naming)

Comment: (Edited) I have at least three other event names with camelCase and they work just fine.

Comment: Also, this solution does not works for me.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with another functionality. The method does nothing.

Comment: So are you saying your `loginDialog` data property is not being set to `false`? What triggers `handleLoginForm()`?

Comment: A submit button which is working fine because my Vuex state is being change before the event emit.

Comment: I'll ask again... _"So are you saying your `loginDialog` data property is not being set to `false`?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution for this error. First of all, I am using the `.sync` modifier to achieve a two-way data binding with a prop:

```
<v-dialog max-width="400" v-model="loginDialog"><login-component :dialog.sync="loginDialog"></login-component></v-dialog>
```

And i just need to emit the new value:

```
this.$emit('update:dialog', false)
```

Comment: Wait, is the issue only that in your original code, you added the event listener on your `<v-dialog>` element when it's meant to be on the `<login-component>`?

Comment: It was indeed the main part of the problem. I fixed that and added logic recommended by Vue.js docs.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil mentioned in his comment, your problem is that you add @login-success="loginDialog = false" on the dialog rather than on the login component from which you make the emit.